# Let $X$ be a compact metric space. If $f:X \to X$ is an isometry, then $f$ is surjective

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, isometry

I'm trying to prove a result mentioned in this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4403738/weakly-shrinking-functions-on-compact-spaces/4408336#4408336), i.e.,

> Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric space and $f:X \to X$ an isometry. Then $f$ is surjective.

Could you confirm if my below attempt is fine?

---

**Proof** Assume the contrary that there is $a \in X$ such that $a \notin f(X)$. Because $f$ is continuous and $X$ compact, we get $f(X)$ is compact. So there is $r>0$ such that
$$
d(a, f(X)) := \inf_{x \in X} d(a, f(x)) \ge r.
$$

We define $(x_n, n \in \mathbb N)$ by $x_0 := a$ and $x_{n+1} := f(x_n)$. Because $f$ is an isometry,
$$
d(x_n, x_m) = d(x_0, x_{m-n})   \ge d(a, f(X))\ge r \quad \forall m > n.
$$

Because $X$ is compact, there is a sub-sequence $\varphi$ of $\mathbb N$ and $b \in X$ such that $x_{\varphi (n)} \to b$. This is a contradiction because
$$
d(x_{\varphi (n)}, x_{\varphi (m)})  \ge r \quad \forall m \neq n.
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Yes, it is essentially the same proof that is provided in the answer to the thread you linked.

Comment: @nicoyanovsky Oh yess, I have not looked the answer there :)

Comment: @ZoeAllen Could you have a check on my attempt of the reverse direction [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4647915/let-x-be-a-compact-metric-space-if-fx-to-x-is-surjective-and-1-lipschit)?